# How to build a search endpoint in a API to find and filter results from a database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my Node API and MongoDB, I'm trying to build an endpoint to search for data in the DB and get back the results to the client. My search goal is to show results from the Profile collection and in that way, I can build my queries to search by first name, surname, company and the combination of it as an example:

```
GET search?fn=joe or ?ln=doe or ?cp=Company or ?fn=...&ln=...&cp=...
```

Practically I can search in different ways and I can get for example all the people working for a company as a result of a search.

I would like to understand how can I achieve that with Mongoose/MongoDB and add also to the query optional a limit/pagination for the coming results.

I tried to make some simple trials but I got stuck as I do not really get it how to proceed next.

```
const SearchController = {
    async getQuery(req, res) {
        try {
            const { fn, ln, cp } = req.query;

            const searchResult = await Profile.find({
                $or: [
                    { firstname: fn },
                    { surname: ln },
                    {
                        experience: {
                            company: cp
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });

            res.status(200).json(searchResult);
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
        }
    }
};
```

The JSON of a profile:

```
{
  "imageUrl": "https://i.pravatar.cc/300",
  "posts": [
    "5e3cacb751f4675e099cd043",
    "5e3cacbf51f4675e099cd045",
    "5e3cacc551f4675e099cd046"
  ],
  "_id": "5e2c98fc3d785252ce5b5693",
  "firstname": "Jakos",
  "surname": "Lemi",
  "email": "lemi@email.com",
  "bio": "My bio bio",
  "title": "Senior IT developer",
  "area": "Copenhagen",
  "username": "Jakos",
  "experience": [
    {
      "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
      "createdAt": "2020-02-04T13:47:37.167Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-02-04T13:47:37.167Z",
      "_id": "5e3975f95fbeec9095ff3d2f",
      "role": "Developer",
      "company": "Google",
      "startDate": "2018-11-09T23:00:00.000Z",
      "endDate": "2019-01-05T23:00:00.000Z",
      "area": "Copenhagen"
    },
    {
      "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
      "createdAt": "2020-02-04T13:59:27.412Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-02-04T13:59:27.412Z",
      "_id": "5e3978bf5e399698e20c56d4",
      "role": "Developer",
      "company": "IBM",
      "startDate": "2018-11-09T23:00:00.000Z",
      "endDate": "2019-01-05T23:00:00.000Z",
      "area": "Copenhagen"
    },
    {
      "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
      "createdAt": "2020-02-07T16:35:43.754Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-02-07T16:35:43.754Z",
      "_id": "5e3d91dfb3a7610ec6ad8ee3",
      "role": "Developer",
      "company": "IBM",
      "startDate": "2018-11-10T00:00:00.000Z",
      "endDate": "2019-01-06T00:00:00.000Z",
      "area": "Copenhagen"
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": "2020-01-25T19:37:32.727Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-02-04T23:14:37.122Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```

The expected results are for example if I search the first name Joe I should get back all the profiles having as first name Joe. Similar for surname and company.

Please provide comments to allow me to understand if you need more scripts from the original code to see.

EDITED added the code modified of the search

```
// Models
const { Profile } = require("../models");
// Error handling
const { ErrorHandlers } = require("../utilities");

const SearchController = {
    async getQuery(req, res) {
        try {
            const { fn, ln, cp } = req.query;

            const query = {
                $or: []
            };

            if (fn) query.$or.push({ firstname: fn });
            if (ln) query.$or.push({ surname: ln });
            if (cp) query.$or.push({ "experience.company": cp });

            const searchResult = Profile.find(query, docs => {
                return docs
            });

            if ((await searchResult).length === 0)
                throw new ErrorHandlers.ErrorHandler(
                    404,
                    "Query do not provided any result"
                );
            res.status(200).json(searchResult);
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
        }
    }
};

module.exports = SearchController;
```

Comment: can you provide more profile, and remove unnesorry data

Comment: `fn, ln, cp` will always have values or can be undifined ?

Comment: So the idea is to search with the combination of the three values. In my opinion, they have always value as a Profile is mandatory to be created with those values

Answer (score 0):

Have tried conditional query and modified your array search query for finding the company,

```
function findUser(fn, ln, cp) {
    const query = {
        $or: []
    }
    if (fn) query.$or.push({ firstname: fn })
    if (ln) query.$or.push({ surname: ln })
    if (cp) query.$or.push({ "experience.company": cp })

    Profile.find(query, function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log(docs);
        }
    });
}

findUser("","","IBM")
```

Comment: I have to search for in different ways not the only the company.

Comment: By the way, trying your way is giving error
{
  "message": "Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with constructor 'NativeTopology'\n    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'\n    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'\n    --- property 'topology' closes the circle"
}

Comment: you can put your current code so i can look at modified code

Comment: how you are invoking the exported function ?

Comment: In the route
router.get("/", SearchCtrl.getQuery);